# How does the updatePolicy in maven really work?

Tags: maven-2, snapshot

When I define an `updatePolicy` in my maven settings it tells maven how often snapshot artifacts shall be downloaded.

If I set it to always it of course downloads every time all snapshots.

I was wondering what happens if I set it to the default value daily or another longer peroid.

Does maven still check whether a new version of the snapshot is available and if so, does it download it although the policy says daily ?

I'm looking for the correct settings to avoid redundant downloads and not to miss a newer snapshot out there.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

> I was wondering what happens if I set it to the default value daily or another longer period.

The [Repository - SNAPSHOT Handling](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVENOLD/Repository+-+SNAPSHOT+Handling) explains it maybe better than the [POM reference](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories):

> Each repository in the project has its
>   own update policy:
>
> - always - always check when Maven is started for newer versions of
>     snapshots
> - never - never check for newer remote versions. Once off manual updates can
>     be performed.
> - daily (default) - check on the first run of the day (local time)
> - interval:XXX - check every XXX minutes

I don't think there is anything to add (except maybe that check != download).

> Does maven still check whether a new version of the snapshot is available and if so, does it download it although the policy says daily ?

Well, no, why would it?

> I'm looking for the correct settings to avoid redundant downloads and not to miss a newer snapshot out there.

Use `always` if you always want Maven to download a *newer version* of snapshots, if available (Maven will always *check* the remote repository but only *download* **if** the version is newer).

Comment: Thanks Pascal. I wasnt sure about the difference of checking vs downloading. So for my continuous build I keep the setting to always

Comment: The first link is very old and refers to a `<snapshot-policy>`.  The tag is actually `<updatePolicy>` as in:
     <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
      </snapshots>

Comment: Good answer - `always` is the safest policy.  As other said, it won't download wastefully, only when a new version becomes available. If you are using internal depenencies and writing SNAPSHOTS to an artifactory, then you probably want the latest one as soon as it's available!