# Error while building Hadoop using Maven

Tags: java, apache, maven, hadoop

I am building Hadoop project using Maven. I am facing below error

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project hadoop-minikdc: Could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-minikdc:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.apache.directory.jdbm:apacheds-jdbm1:bundle:2.0.0-M2 in https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-    4.0.0.xsd">
  <parent>
<groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
<artifactId>hadoop-project</artifactId>
<version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<relativePath>../../hadoop-project</relativePath>
  </parent>
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
  <artifactId>hadoop-minikdc</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description>Apache Hadoop MiniKDC</description>
  <name>Apache Hadoop MiniKDC</name>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>apacheds-core-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-M15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>api-ldap-schema-data</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>apacheds-interceptor-kerberos</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-M15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>api-ldap-schema-data</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-shared</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-M15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-kerberos</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-M15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>apacheds-ldif-partition</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-M15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>api-ldap-schema-data</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>apacheds-mavibot-partition</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-M15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>api-ldap-schema-data</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
  <artifactId>api-all</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0-M20</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
      <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>xpp3</groupId>
      <artifactId>xpp3</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
      <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>apacheds-jdbm-partition</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-M15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>api-ldap-schema-data</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
  <artifactId>apacheds-protocol-ldap</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0-M15</version>
  <scope>compile</scope>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>org.apache.directory.api</groupId>
      <artifactId>api-ldap-schema-data</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Please post your pom.xml, moreover as the error says, the dependency that you are looking for is not there in specified url location.

Comment: I have pasted pom.xml. Please let me know what is the problem

Comment: Duplicate problem, see:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932923/why-cant-maven-find-an-osgi-bundle-dependency?lq=1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9932923/why-cant-maven-find-an-osgi-bundle-dependency?lq=1) This problem is also known as a bug: [https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12839](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-12839)

Answer (score 0):

This is related to the [update policy](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3805329/1064245) that Maven uses to update the dependencies in your local repository. One solution is to try to manually delete the directory containing the dependency `org.apache.directory.jdbm:apacheds-jdbm1:bundle:2.0.0-M2` in your local repo, and re-launch the build.

You can also force updating all dependencies by passing `-U` to Maven, e.g.:

`mvn clean install -U`

Answer (score 0):

If this dependency is private, you need to add related information to you maven setting file in ~/.m2/settings.xml

Answer (score 0):

From your statement, you say you could not resolve dependencies for project org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-minikdc:jar:3.0.0-SNAPSHOT. Ok, I think it's your wrong proxy of maven, and your cannot download this jar. Please check your proxy and again it. Please go to the dir. of ~/.m2/settings.xml to revice your setting.

like this

```
<proxy>
  <id>optional</id>
  <active>true</active>
  <protocol>http</protocol>
  <username></username>
  <password></password>
  <host>child-prc.intel.com</host>
  <port>913</port>
  <nonProxyHosts>local.net|some.host.com</nonProxyHosts>
</proxy>
```