# How does maven handle same version but different jar?

Tags: maven

I've a project named `main-backend` which consume `api-backend`

I've updated `api-backend`, and did a mvn install locally so that my `main-backend` can consume my updated SNAPSHOT jar.

However if someone else pushes `api-backend` with `mvn deploy`, what will happen? How does maven determine which SNAPSHOT to use?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How does the updatePolicy in maven really work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3805329/how-does-the-updatepolicy-in-maven-really-work)

Answer (score 0):

the role is if they are snapshots , it will be override
if it is release, it will refuse to deploy to your repo